# git commit -m won't involk vim to edit

Tags: git

I can use `git commit -a` to commit a message and it open vim to edit. However this command automatically commit everything that has been modified. I would really like to use `git commit -m' to commit. However this command won't invoke vim editor. How to solve this issue.

Comment: So you would like to run `git commit -m "my message"`, and have the editor open with "my message" already added to the commit message?

Comment: @chepner Yes, I would like to edit more carefully of this message.

Comment: So, just type `git commit` without any arguments?

Comment: @1615903 This actually works, thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This option seems to be just what you're looking for:

```
   -e, --edit
       The message taken from file with -F, command line with -m, and from
       commit object with -C are usually used as the commit log message
       unmodified. This option lets you further edit the message taken
       from these sources.
```

Comment: You are brilliant ! You know what I want

Answer (score 1):

You can use `git commit` without any arguments. It will start your configured text editor (vim by default) so you can type the commit message there.

Comment: The first sentence is right, the second one is not true, you need to set your default editor to vim explicitly.